# jQuery / php / mysql - how to manipulate a mysqli_query without reloading the page?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I have a table containing data read from a MySQL database via PHP. The first column holds all item names. Now, on clicking a **td** element in the first column of the table would link to a page with more detailed information about the item contained in the **td**.

Now I came up with the following idea:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#table td:first-child').click(function() {
        $('div.main').animate({
            height: "50px"
        }, 600);
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('div.data').fadeIn(1000);
        }, 600);
    });
});
```

**div.main** is the div-container that has the table included. What I want to do now is to slide that container up and fade a new **div**-container in, right below it, the new container include()s a PHP page which holds a dynamic query *(pseudocode, no string escaping, simplified version)*:

```
SELECT detail FROM items WHERE items.name = $_GET['name'];
```

What I couldn't figure out is if and how I can tell the PHP file that is included in the in-fading div-container which item name it has to grab details for, off the database.

Right now I can read the item name via **JavaScript/jQuery**, but I couldn't figure a way out to pass that value to the PHP file without having to reload the page.

Any ideas or suggestions welcome!

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, that's exactly what I was looking for! I've chosen @EthanBrown's answer though because it appears to be to be the most simple solution. I certainly can make use of Ohgodwhy's example, too. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [asynchronous JavaScript and XML (AJAX)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).  It sounds intimidating, but fortunately jQuery makes it very easy.

You can call [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) directly, but for most cases, you can use one of the convenience wrappers.  In this case, I think [$.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) will meet your needs.

So, let's say your PHP file is called `detail_ajax.php` and it returns the HTML you wish to put in your div (with class `data`).  All you would have to do then is this:

```
$('div.data').load( '/detail_ajax.php', function(data){
    $(this).html(data);
});
```

If you want to pass data TO `detail_ajax.php`, you can pass it along this way:

```
$('div.data').load( '/detail_ajax.php', { 'someField' : 'someValue' },
    function(data) {
        $(this).html(data);
    }
});
```

In `detail_ajax.php`, if you examine `$_POST['someField']`, you will see the value passed in.

Comment: (A)synchronous (J)avascript (A)nd (X)ML (AJAX) ;)

Comment: Thanks, Alejandro, I actually caught that and meant to correct it, but then forgot, so thanks for the reminder!

Comment: I had to change your example slightly to make it work though;   `$('div.data').load('/pages/details.php?item=' + item);`, where 'item' is a variable containing the clicked **td**'s .attr('name') value, which is set to the item's name.

Comment: Ah, yes, I should have mentioned that.  When you do it that way, you can access the variables via the `$_GET` array.  When you do it the way I suggested, you can access the variables via `$_POST`, so it all depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using ajax. Output your query on a separate page in JSON format then fetch it using jquery ajax

Answer (score 1):

you need to use ajax to do the same thing. create an event like onclick and call a 
method on click call ajax set variable in js and pass it to and do as you want, 
show data in particular div in response. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). However, 3 things will need to take place for this to happen as you intend.

First, we need a reference held in the HTML that is generated by the table so we can streamline the server request. When you generate the table, add a unique `data-name` string to the TD.

```
<td data-name="<?php echo $row['name']; ?>">
```

If, for instance, the td's were generated in a `foreach` loop, where we expect an `array` to be returned.

Now, we need to detect the request on our page so we can properly return the data to the browser, we'll look for `$_GET['name']` as per your example.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['name'])):
    $mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
    $ret;
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT detail FROM items WHERE items.name = ?')):
        $stmt ->bind_param('s', $_GET['name']);
        $stmt ->execute();
        $stmt ->bind_result($details); // we only want one column
        $stmt ->fetch(); //get our row
        $ret['success'] = TRUE;
        $ret['html'] =  '<div>'. $details .'</div>';
    else:
        $ret['success'] = FALSE; 
    endif;
    echo json_encode($ret); //return to the browser
endif;
?>
```

Now we need to employ ajax to bridge the gap between the server and the browser.

**Edit** - I forgot to modify the click function.

```
$('#table td:first-child').click(function() {
    $('div.main').animate({
        height:'0px'                    
    }, function(){
        //once the animation completes
        $.ajax({
            url: '/',
            type: 'GET', //this is default anyway
            data:{name: $(this).data('name')}, //send the name from the td clicked
            dataType: 'json', //what we expect back from the server
            success: function(data){ //will fire when complete. data is the servers response
                if(data.success !== false){
                    $('div').html(data.html);
                    $('div.main').animate({
                        height: "50px"
                    }, 600);
                }else{
                    alert("Something went wrong");
                }
            }
        }); 
    }, 600);
});
```